# 500 internal error when getting thumbnail

Tags: box-api

I'm writing iOS client using Box.net API 2.0,

When I'm trying to request a thumbnail using files/{file_id}/thumbnail.png?min_height=256&min_width=256

I randomly get 500 internal error, and I can't get thumbnail even though I resend the request, does anyone get this error too?

To box.net api team, here is my request_id, don't know if it's useful for debugging

"request_id":"126738691351a5a9e4269ad"

Answer (score 0):

Please message the API team at api@box.com–sounds like there might be something weird going on with a specific file.